# Are 'What is a better way to write this?' questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

Do we allow *'What is a better way to write this?'* questions on this site? If not, I feel [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48651/use-of-different-tenses-to-express-present-fact-on-past-action) question is one of those.

The issue with those types of questions is that there is no definite answer and there can be many equally good responses. Also, it is unlikely that it will be useful for future readers.

This is not the same as questions which ask for alternate/better words/phrases for a presented word/phrase given a specific context; these can be useful and excellent questions.

Answer (score 4):

Such questions are off-topic as a rule, unless they involve a question about a particular grammatical construction. In general, they can be migrated to http://writers.stackexchange.com, though low-quality questions of this sort are liable to be closed there, as well.

Comment: Please note Writers.SE has specific [critique guidelines](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/167#167) for such questions, so if it's clearly not a good match (especially "please give me any comments whatsoever you have" questions and proofreading requests), you can skip the migration and just close.